# Is it possible to restore a SQL 7 DB to SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-7

I have an old SQL 7 DB .bak file I am trying to work with now. I tried to restore the backup in SQL 2008, but it said that it was unable to work with the file. Does anyone know how I could restore this DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install SQL Server 7, 2000, or 2005 and restore the backup to one of those first.

- SQL 2000/2005 - Restore the backup, export, and restore to 2008.
- SQL 7 - Restore the backup and use the SQL Server 2008 import functionality to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

The database you are attempting to restore to is probably set with version 8 compatibility, not 7. That would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: This DB was created about 5 years ago. I only have the .bak of the file at this point.